# How to close all tabs/windows of a specific chrome user/profile?

Tags: google-chrome

I have several users defined in my chrome browser. Each user has several windows open and each window has several tabs open.

I'd like to close all the windows/tabs of a specific user, while still be able to:

1. Keep all the other users' windows/tabs open.
2. Have all the closed user's windows/tabs restored when reopening the profile.

Any idea if there's some UI button or keyboard shortcut I missed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not possible right now, but you can star this feature request if you'd like to see it introduced:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130656

Comment: I did. ;) May be we start signing some change org petition now? :)

Comment: Quote from that page! -> Comment 37 by ew...@chromium.org, Yesterday (42 hours ago)
Status: Fixed
This has been addressed in M55 with the new update to the user menu, rolling out in the next week. When there is more than one window open for a given profile, a new "Close all your windows" button will appear at the bottom of the user menu.

Thanks for all your feedback, everyone.

Comment: (for the record): version 58 's been release recently and still it lacks of the fix.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka this answer is outdated and wrong now, please change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

It seems that a new features was introduced in chrome's stable build - mine is 55.0.2883.75 (64-bit). See screencap below.

It's a new option in the **profile's left click**: `Close all your windows`.

The problem is that it doesn't always restore all the closed windows and sometimes doesn't even restore at all, even though my startup setting is set to `Continue where you left off`.

EDIT: It seems that there are issues with the **restoration** and **cleanup**. More info [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130656#c46).

[image]

edit(2017-08-09) - No need for right click anymore. Left click does the job.

Comment: Note also that the extensions are not closed when pressing this button which is basically 50% of the reason for having the button.

Comment: @HaydenMoulds - Thanks. That's what I meant by the term "cleanup".

Comment: As of version 63, there is no such option anymore.

Comment: @Tgr - They changed it to left click. Exists in version `63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)`. Changed description to left click.

Comment: Not in my browser (which is the same build): https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLiMk.png

Comment: @Tgr - have you defined several profiles? https://i.imgur.com/g2c1aO2.png

Comment: Nvm, I only had one window for that profile, and Chrome is apparently clever enough to not show that option if there aren't multiple windows to close.

Answer (score 2):

This has been possible for a while. Here's a screenshot from Chromium 71:

[image: Chromium exit profile]

There are some bugs still, e.g. [some windows may not be restored](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130656#c138), or some extensions may keep running. But if you have one window per profile, its tabs are saved and restored fine.

Comment: Only one window per profile? That's absurd! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is confirmed that it works in MacOS version 93 of Google Chrome by indeed left clicking on the circle of the Account

[image]

One needs to click on "Close 2 Windows", which is not present when only one window is open (in that case you just close the single window)